# My question was deleted by a moderator for "bumping" it, which I didn't do

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-questions, moderators

[Simple way to do a weighted hot deck imputation in Stata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324137/simple-way-to-do-a-weighted-hot-deck-imputation-in-stata?noredirect=1#comment101253004_53324137)

I am baffled. A moderator deleted the question, saying "Stop using edits on the question and answer to bump the post"

I haven't edited the question in several months. All I have done recently was to delete both of my answers (as neither had been upvoted after several months), and converted one of the deleted answers to a comment. OK, technically I edited the answers, but only to add a reason for why I was deleting them. I honestly have no idea if editing an answer just prior to deleting an answer bumps the question (I guess yes, but that is news to me and wasn't my intent).

Anyway, I don't see anything that I did wrong. Admittedly this question failed to get any upvotes over several months, so I can't claim it's a huge loss to the [Stata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stata) community, but even so this seems like a very severe and capricious behavior by a moderator.

@JonasWilms & @opa: OK, if you really want the full reasoning. Part of my thinking was that some folks are OK with answering your own question and others aren’t (I know it is officially OK, some don’t like it, and that’s how it is). So an advantage of deleting two unappreciated answers is it might encourage another answer. But the bigger reasons were specific to each answer.

The first answer (no code) was really just an extended comment, and I was initially unsure of making it an answer. Hence, after getting many views, but no upvotes, I figured it was just more concise and appropriate as a comment. I am kind of surprised if anyone would have a problem with that.

The second answer (the one with code) is one that I’ve continued to work on. I’ve since found some bugs and made some improvements. The options were (1) leave the answer up with bugs I’ve since fixed, (2) make the fixes to the answer, which no one cares about, thus “bumping” it many more times, (3) or just delete it!

It seemed clear that (3) was the way to go. How do you think the person who flagged me would have liked it had I gone with (2)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- I see you marked "status-completed" and I guess that is true for the most part but I remain a bit baffled by the initial deletion and maybe the cause was just a moderator going overboard but I was also wondering if there is anything else I could have done besides post here and in general is there anything that can be done about moderators unreasonably (at least IMO here) deleting questions?  And I'm also curious if there is anything I did wrong here (not that I can tell, but I'm happy to listen to criticism)

Comment: Mods are also human and sometimes make mistakes, not everything they do that we don't like is done on purpose. As for other ways of doing this, a custom flag might have worked but it's not uncommon for issues like this to be brought to meta and resolved here either so I don't see how you did anything wrong.

Comment: It's btw also possible to edit the answer *after* deleting it if you want to avoid bumps.

Comment: But why did you delete the answers at all?

Comment: @ivarni Editing deleted answers still bumps the question.

Comment: @Catija I didn't know that. Thanks. I'll make a mental note.

Comment: Can you please answer why you deleted your answers?  I don't see "not upvoted" as justification for removing them, i mean *you made them* and *you also made the question* so theoretically they weren't wrong and were usefull.  Only one person upvoted your question, so odds are most people didn't need this question answered.

Comment: @JonasWilms sorry for the slow response, I’m on vacation.  I edited the question to elaborate.  Perhaps it would have been better not to delete the answers, but the above is my rationale fwiw since you asked.

Comment: @opa see preceding comment

Comment: @JohnE  Those are still pretty lame explanations, If A1 was NAA, then sure it should have been a comment.  If A2 was an answer with bugs you should have just fixed it, deleting was not the right move. The fact that you believe some people don't like self answers (which I've never seen, there are however self answers that use knowledge about the "real" question no one else could have known) does not factor into this equation.  There's no correlation between "answers exist without up-votes" and "encouraging other answers". The person flagged you because you were doing weird things.

Comment: @opa I disagree but I really just want to be done with this at this point. It seems like maybe there is a mild consensus that I should not have deleted the answers (based on the upvotes your response is getting) so I’m going to put things back like they were a week ago with the intent of not fiddling with any of this in the future except to later replace my code with a link to git hub if I ever get around to uploading it there.

Comment: @opa but note that the flag was not suggesting anything weird, but rather that I was attempting to repeatedly bump the question.  I realize there can be a difference of opinions on my various actions (e.g. to delete or not) but I think all my edits had a rationale, whether you agree with every single one or not.

Comment: @JohnE, right, they flagged you thinking that your weird actions were you trying to bump the question.  No one can read your mind, it doesn't matter what your intentions were, these actions looked nonsensical from the outside.

Comment: @opa I’m having trouble understanding what is so weird about deleting one’s own answers with no votes and I’ve done it many other times.  And of course there is actually a badge for deleting one’s own post if it had 3 upvotes.  Anyway, that’s just my view, I’m fine with agreeing to disagree on a topic that has probably run its course here.

Comment: (Hopefully) closing point: I’m done with this.  If a moderator or someone with stata tag privileges wants to delete or modify some or all of my question or answers please go ahead.  I am happy to submit to the group consensus on this one, if it exists.

Comment: Btw, what was initially very weird about this question was it shot up to 300 views very quickly but got no votes or responses except for a single comment.  That seemed very strange and have no idea why it happened (search engine related?). After that initial boom, it accumulated views very slowly.  It is the strangest experience I’ve had with a question by far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I responded to a flag on your post as follows.

[image]

Looking at the edits on both the question and the two answers you posted it is an excessive number of bumps. *Some* users deliberately take advantage of edits to bump their posts to the front page. In fact we have an automatic flag that trips when a post is edited too frequently.

So, I was exuberant in deleting your post - admittedly it was the second flag I had for editing bumps, so that is on me. It's undeleted now.

Comment: Maybe a lock is a less destructive option here.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes  I locked the other post of the flag I handled - in this case it didn't look like the question was going to be answered and I was a bit blase in going delete.

Comment: Ha, I know exactly who flagged it.  I “bumped” it a bunch of times just because I edited the question and and answers several times.  But these were almost all months ago when the question was fresh and some were probably just minutes apart.  The recent “bumps” were to delete and I had no idea that was a bump. Anybody who cares can examine the edits and decide if I “bumped” it.

Comment: Thanks, Yvette, I can see how this looked from your view.  This issue IMO is this was a petty flag and the person who did it reallly should have handled it differently, especially as they have Stata tag powers

Comment: @JohnE the thing is. we're not mind readers and there's patterns of behaviour that are not ok - so it's a bit of a rocky territory- we can only use our best judgement on the day and given your attitude you seem reasonable and nice. Not everyone reacts that way

Comment: @JohnE My question is how do you know the person that flagged has Stata tag powers?

Comment: @JohnE Is it possible that you hold a grudge against Stata regulars for not up-voting your question and answers? I am asking based on these two (deleted) answers of yours ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377447/) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377454), and their edits)

Comment: @JohnE Congratulations for being awarded the Inquisitive badge by the way. You got it right after your question was undeleted.

Comment: @PearlySpencer the only stata regulars I know of are you and nick and I don’t have a grudge against either of you.